# Is it possible to refer to multiple documents in a mongo db query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have a collection containing the following documents:

```
...
{
   event_counter : 3 
   event_type: 50
   event_data: "yaya"
}
{
   event_counter : 4 
   event_type: 100
   event_data: "whowho"
}
...
```

Is it possible to ask for:

```
for each document, e where e.event_type == 100
    get me any document f where 
       f.event_counter = e.event_counter+1
```

or equivalently:

```
find each f, where f.event_counter==e.event_counter+1 && e.event_type==100
```

Comment: it's only possible to ask this in multiple queries or in aggregation framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way for you to approach this is on the application side, using multiple queries.  You would want to run a query to match all documents with e.event_type = 100, like this one:

```
db.collection.find({"e.event_type" : 100});
```

Then, you'll have to write some logic to iterate through the results and run more queries to find documents with the right value of f.event_counter.

I am not sure it's possible to do this using MongoDB's aggregation framework.  If it is possible, it will be quite a complicated query.